# How do I properly format a .js file with JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to implementing JavaScript and jQuery into my website and am having trouble with how to format the code. The code I'm using each works separately but when I combine the following code together in one .js document the second part of the code (slides) doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? EDIT: It's the slideshow that won't work.

Thanks.

This is for one element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav-icon4').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$(".menu").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

This is for another element on the same page:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

function nextSlide() {
slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
```

HTML:

In the head section I put:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<ul id="slides">
   <li class="slide showing"><img src="images/run1.jpg" alt="run" class="show"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/oregonpin.jpg" alt="oregon pin on map" class="show" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/shortswim.jpg" alt="swim" class="show" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/cycle1.jpg" alt="bike" class="show" /></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/run2.jpg" alt="run" class="show"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/run3.jpg" alt="run" class="show"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/cycle2.jpg" alt="bike" class="show"/></li>
<li class="slide"><img src="images/swim1.jpg" alt="swim" class="show"/></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#slides {
position: relative;
height: 300px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}
.slide {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 90%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;

-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s;
-o-transition: opacity 1s;
transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
opacity: 1;
z-index: -1;
}
.slide {
font-size: 40px;
padding: 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #333;
color: #fff;
}
.show {
height: 80%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Regarding *formatting*, you should indent your code to make it easier to read. As far as getting those two code snippets to work within one page, you shouldn't need to do anything special, they don't conflict with each other. How did you combine them? Did you remember to include jquery.js on the page too? When you say "it doesn't work", what actually happens? Please check your browser's dev console for error messages.

Comment: please show a snippet of your html that is using this.  Or at least where you're connecting the page to the js file.

Comment: I added the html and css. It's a slideshow that isn't working. It doesn't do anything other than display the first image.

Comment: but where in your html do you link to your js file or jquery?  This is the part that we need to see.

Comment: Edited above with what I put in the head

Comment: The scripts/scripts.js `<script>` element would need to be *after* the `<ul>` (e.g., just before the closing `</body>` tag) or it will run before the `<ul>` has been parsed by the browser. Or you could move the slides JS code inside the document ready handler from the other code.

Comment: I ended up putting the code for the slideshow into another file and linking it at the bottom like that and everything works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The scripts/scripts.js  element would need to be after the  (e.g., just before the closing  tag) or it will run before the  has been parsed by the browser. Or you could move the slides JS code inside the document ready handler from the other code.

This was from user: nnnnn

I put the slideshow code in a new file and linked it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting code of 2nd snippet just after

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

of first snippet.